# What is "C sort order" in pm-action manpage?

Tags: power-management

From manpage `pm-action(8)`:

> ```
> /etc/pm/sleep.d, /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d
> ```
>
> Programs in these directories (called hooks) are combined
>        and executed in **C sort order** before suspend and hibernate
>        with as argument ´suspend´ or ´hibernate´.
>
> Afterwards they
>        are called in reverse order with argument ´resume´ and
>        ´thaw´ respectively.
>
> If both directories contain **a similar
>        named file**, the one in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` will get preference. 
>        It is possible to disable a hook in the distribution
>        directory by putting a non-executable file in
>        `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, or by adding it to the `HOOK_BLACKLIST`
>        configuration variable.

What is "C sort order"?

Does "a similar   named file" mean two files with the **same** filename?

I have two files `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_cpu_freq`. 
When resume and thaw, which one is run first and which second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The C lexical sort order is very simple: characters with a lower numeric value sort before characters with a higher one. As almost all UNIX-derived systems nowadays use [extended ASCII-derived character sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_groups), the ordering would therefore be 8-bit as follows:

- Control characters: NUL-US (`^@`-`^_`: 0-26)
- Printable characters:  (space)-`/`, `0`-`9`, `:`-`@`, `A`-`Z`, `[`-`` ` `` , `a`-`z`, `{`-`~`
- Extended characters: stuff afterwards (depends on the codepage)

Because of this, here are some filenames, in order:

```
!afile
0Afile
0_file
0afile
0~file
20-cpu_freq
20_cpu_freq
94Cpufreq
94cpufreq
```

By "similar named file", the two directory lists are combined, and if two file have the same name, the one in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` wins: if you had `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/94cpufreq`, the latter would be read.

The order which these will be run is dictated by the operation that `pm-utils` is doing (from [HOWTO.hooks](https://github.com/VictorLowther/pm-utils/blob/master/pm/HOWTO.hooks)):

> **SLEEP.D SPECIFIC NOTES**
>
> For any given sleep/wakeup cycle, the hooks in `sleep.d` are run twice:
>
> - Once in C lexical sort order before the system goes to sleep, and
> - Once in reverse C lexical sort order when the system wakes up.

**TL;DR:** `20_cpu_freq` will be run first and `94cpufreq` second when preparing to sleep, and the other way around when waking up.